# Unwind Segue Xcode 6.1 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I know this was a problem in the Xcode betas and I read that this was fixed in the Xcode 6 GM, but I am having trouble with it now. I have create an unwind segue but it doesn't unwind properly. I have both views set to their respective custom View Controller, I have the unwind function in the view controller I want to unwind to, and this is the code I'm using:

```
@IBAction func unwindToObjectives(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Can someone please help explain what I'm doing wrong? I know there is a work around, but I am trying to avoid using it. Also, I apologize for asking this menial question, I'm extremely new to Swift and iOS development.

Comment: So what is wrong? What result are you getting? Does it go back to the the destination view controller or not? Is the unwindToObjectives: method called?

Comment: When I click the button that is supposed to initiate the segue, nothing happens. It just stays on the view, rather than unwinding to the destination view. The method is called by the button, but it doesn't unwind.

Comment: Works fine for me in Xcode 6.1 with Swift. Can you share more info? Assuming you want to unwind from VC B back to VC A, how did you navigate from A to B in the first place? Segues all in IB or programmatic? All push or all present? Non-adaptive segues or adaptive?

Comment: I am unwinding from VC B back to TVC A. I navigated using a show detail segue. I used a manual segue. They are all in IB (except the unwind)

Comment: can you post to github?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. In the end I just remade the custom TVC (with the segue), deleted the VC, and change the segue to a modal on and it work. I don't know how that helped, but it did.

Comment: What is your controller structure? Are they both stand alone view controllers or are they embedded in anything? Is this an iPhone or iPad app?